# Additivity of degree

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\Lambda = \Omega^2$, the **product** of $\Omega$ two times, be maps of spheres. We know that $\text{deg}(\Lambda) = 2\text{deg}(\Omega)$. How does one show this fact using the formula for the degree? I.e.

$$ \text{deg}(\Omega) = \frac{\int_S \Omega^*(\omega)}{\int_S \omega}$$

I have tried for dimensions $1$ and $2$, but I am unsure how to use the pullback for a cleaner proof. I am mainly interested in the dimension $3$ case, though.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you clarify?

Comment: I have tried for 1 and 2 dimensions, but I am unsure how to use the pullback for a cleaner proof. I am mainly interested in the dimension 3 case, though.

Comment: Degree is actually multiplicative wrt composition, not additive (think about maps $z^n\colon S^1 \to S^1$). Let $f\colon S^k \to S^k$, $\omega$ a non-zero element of $H^k(S^k)$. Then $f^*(\omega) = n\omega$ for some $n$, and from your formula you can see in fact $n = deg(f)$. Then if $g\colon S^k \to S^k$ is another map, $(g\circ f)^*(\omega) = f^*\circ g^*(\omega) = f^*(deg(g)\omega) = deg(g) f^*(\omega) = deg(g)deg(f) \omega$ and therefore $deg(g \circ f) = deg(g) deg(f)$. In particular $deg(\Omega^2) = deg(\Omega)^2$.

Comment: @William, thanks for your answer. What I meant by $\Omega^2$ is $\Omega \cdot \Omega$, not $\Omega \circ\Omega$. I meant product, not composition.

Comment: Ok, then I still don't actually know what you mean by "$\cdot$" or "product" here. Is it the group operation in $\pi_k(S^k)$? Are you implicitly using the group structure on $S^3$ (which doesn't exist on $S^k$ unless $k=0, 1, 3$)?

Comment: Say, let $\Omega(\phi) = e^{2 \pi i n \phi}$, so that $(\Omega \cdot \Omega)(\phi) = e^{4 \pi i n \phi}$

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you are particularly interested in $S^3$, which actually has a group structure, I will consider the case of self-maps of Lie groups (otherwise you haven't made it clear what a "product of maps" $S^k \to S^k$ is supposed to mean in general, since $S^k$ is only a group if $k\in \{0, 1, 3\}$). Caveat: there are some details I'm not 100% sure about because I don't remember how to prove them or where to find a citation.

Let $G$ be a closed, $n$-dimensional Lie group with group operation $\mu\colon G\times G \to G$, let $\omega \in H^n_{dR}(G)$ be non-zero, let $f, g\colon G\to G$ be a smooth functions, and let $f\cdot g\colon G \to G$ be defined by $(f\cdot g)(x) = \mu(f(x), g(x))$. We want to compute

$$deg (f\cdot g) = \frac{\int_G (f\cdot g)^*\omega}{\int_G \omega}  $$

so the first step should be to ask what is the effect of $f\cdot g$ on cohomology. $f\cdot g$ is actually the composition

$$ G \stackrel{f\times g}{\to} G\times G \stackrel{\mu}{\to} G.$$

**Claim:** $\mu^*(\omega) = \omega\otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \omega$. (I don't remember a proof for this right now, it's possible that it's not actually true.)

From this claim it would follow that $(f\times g)^*\mu^*(\omega) = f^*(\omega)g^*(1) + f^*(1)g^*(\omega) = f^*(\omega) + g^*(\omega)$, so we get

$$deg (f\cdot g) = \frac{\int_G (f\cdot g)^*\omega}{\int_G \omega} = \frac{\int_G (f^*\omega + g^*\omega)}{\int_G \omega}$$ $$ = \frac{\int_G f^*\omega}{\int_G \omega} + \frac{\int_G g^*\omega}{\int_G \omega} = def(f) + deg(g) $$

---

For maps $f,g\colon S^k \to S^k$ for arbitrary $k$, there is no underlying group structure on $S^k$ to use to define the "product" of $f$ and $g$ (unless $k \in \{0, 1, 3\}$). Alternatively you can use the "concatenation" operation $\ast$ used to define the group structure on $\pi_k(S^k)$ (coming from the fact that every sphere admits a *co*-group structure) and try to work with a smooth approximation. Then you again need to verify that $(f\ast g)^*(\omega) = f^*(\omega) + g^*(\omega)$, I don't have an argument for this yet.